# Node.js app on a PHP website

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have a PHP website on a shared Linux server.

I have a node.js and socket.io chat application on a different server.

What is the easiest way for me to have this simple chat application appear on my website?

Comment: It should be shown on the PHP server? Just google for iFrame

Comment: So the standard way of achieving this is to use an iFrame?

Comment: With that you can show other websites on your. It is the simplest way. Example: <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach chat window in the bootstrapping of your application using iframe. Chat window should points to the chat server.